# How can I reload specific application context bean dynamically?

Tags: spring, groovy, java-8, javabeans, autowired

I'm currently working on a groovy based application on the top of JDK8 and spring-beans:4.3.1.RELEASE. I need to introduce a method by which I can recreate a targeted bean by its name at runtime. I did something like this, but my current implementation has no effect when I @autowire the specific bean, the property changed at application runtime are not reflected on @autowired bean after calling the reload method. context.refresh() working fine for me, but it recreates entire beans which are ultimately overkilling my process. So basically, I'm looking for a way by which I can reload a specific bean by its name only.

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext

@Override    
public synchronized Map<String, ?> reloadBean(String beanName) {

    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext

    def beanObject = context.getBean(beanName)

    /* Reload the properties file */
    reloadProperties()

    /* Bean factroy method call */
    beanObject.buildFromConfiguration()

    DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry defaultSingletonBeanRegistry = (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry) context.getBeanFactory()

    /* Destroy the given bean. */
    defaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(beanName)

    if(!defaultSingletonBeanRegistry.containsSingleton(beanName)) {

        /* Add the given singleton object to the singleton cache of this factory. */
        defaultSingletonBeanRegistry.registerSingleton(beanName, beanObject)

        beanLoadStatus.put(beanName, "Application context bean reloaded successfully.")
    } else {
        beanLoadStatus.put(beanName, "Failed to release old application context bean.")
    }

    return beanLoadStatus
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look to the RefreshScope annotation? It can help you by being more selective with the beans you want to refresh. You can check it out in the following link:

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/docs/1.0.x/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope

According to the reference (http://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-commons-parent/1.1.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/context/config/annotation/RefreshScope.html)

> Convenience annotation to put a @Bean definition in refresh scope. Beans annotated this way can be refreshed at runtime and any components that are using them will get a new instance on the next method call, fully initialized and injected with all dependencies.